# Linking entities in different JSF pages

Tags: jsf, jpa, jsf-2, eclipselink

I am trying to learn JSF, EJB and eclipselink, JPA using the following example:

an index.xhtml page displays a list of employees from an Employee Entity:

Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="EMPLOYEE")
@NamedQuery(name="Employee.findAll", query="SELECT s FROM Employee s")
public class Employee implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private String empcode;

    private String empdesc;
```

SessionBean function:

```
 public List<Employee> getEmployeeFindAll() {
        return em.createNamedQuery("Employee.findAll").getResultList();
    }
```

index.xhtm:

```
<body>
    <h:form>
    <h:dataTable border="1" var="temp" id="d1"
        value="#{EmployeeManagedBean.EmployeeFindAll}">
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText id="o1" value="EmpTable"></h:outputText>
        </f:facet>
        <h:column id="c1">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText id="o2" value="#{temp.empcode}"></h:outputText>
            </f:facet>

        </h:column>
        <h:column id="c2">
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText id="o3" value=""#{temp.empdesc}""> /h:outputText>
            </f:facet>

        </h:column>
    </h:dataTable>
    </h:form>
```

So far so good, `index.xhtml` works fine. Now I have a second entity `EmployeeQualification`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="EMPQUA")
@NamedQuery(name="Empqua.findAll", query="SELECT n FROM Empqua n")
public class Empqua implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @EmbeddedId
    private EmpquaPK id;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    private Date since;
```

where `@EmbeddedId` is :

```
@Embeddable
public class EmpquaPK implements Serializable {
    //default serial version id, required for serializable classes.
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @Column(name="EMPCODE", length = 8)
    private String empcode;
    @Column(name="QUACODE")
    private String quacode;
```

What I want to do is use the `index.xhtml` datatable contents as links to a second page e.g `empqua.xhtml` where I will display a data table which will contain all Empqua records for the selected Empcode.

So what I think I need is a function in my `EmpquaManagedbean` which will take `empcode` as input, call the corresponding function in my EmpquaSessionbean and return a list of Empqua objects, containing all records of Empqua for the given empcode:

EmpquaManagedbean:

```
public List<Empqua> getEmpquaforSelectedEmpcode(String empcode){

         return getSessionFacade().getEmpquaByEmpcode(empcode);

    }
```

Empqua Session Bean:

```
public List<Empqua> getEmpquaByEmpcode(String empcode){

                return em.createQuery("SELECT a FROM Empqua a where (a.id.empcode) = :empcode").setParameter("empcode", empcode).getResultList();
    }
```

Now my problems begin. I need to pass the parameter `empcode` from my `index.xhtml` datatable (when the link is clicked) to the managed bean and return a page `empqua.xhtml`. The first problem is, how do I pass the parameter?

```
<h:commandLink value="#{temp.empcode}" action="#{EmpQuaManagedBean.getEmpquaforSelectedEmpcode(temp.empcode)}"></h:commandLink>
```

returns a method not found exception. Furthermore I probably need to call this through another function which will return String `empqua.xhtml` to move to the next page.

Comment: Please start by reading this Q/A https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2090033/why-jsf-calls-getters-multiple-times and improve your code

Comment: Secondly, read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909267/differences-between-action-and-actionlistener (especially regarding return values)

Comment: And the error in the stacktrace will show what method signature it looks for...